# HTTP2 on FreeBSD / a2enmod

Tags: apache-httpd, freebsd, http

I'm wondering if it is a good idea to install/configure http2 on my apache on FreeBSD10.

This machines serves some websites. What I wonder is: is this stable? Is it secure? Any opinions on if I better postpone? Other thoughts?

Also I see on a lot of sites documentation using a2enmod. However on my FreeBSD install I don't have this tool. Is this specific to Linux distros?

Thanks in advance!